# Python 3 - How to Properly Load Modules

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following simple folders on the same level and would like to know what's good practice to load `foo1` and `subfoo1` from `foo2`? Further, I want to load `foo2` from `main`.

```
MyFolder/main.py
MyFolder/Folder1/Subfolder1/subfoo1.py
MyFolder/Folder1/foo1.py                                                                   
MyFolder/Folder2/foo2.py
```

I know that there are similar questions but I fail to understand best practice. So far, I'm using `sys.path.append()`. Would there be a purpose for `__init__.py` here? I appreciate some advice.

Comment: Is your `main.py` the only file that is going to be run (as `__main__`), right?

Comment: Yes and no, I've created a lil toolbox for data analysis where the main analysis comes together in `main.py`. However, I may also use `foo2` as a stand-alone tool (well depending on `foo1`).

Comment: Sry, I had to correct my comment for a typo.

Comment: Are you at all familliar with [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)? It's not clear to me if you're having a specific problem with your imports, or if you just haven't learned yet how to make them work without messing around in `sys.path`.

Comment: The latter point is true, thx for the link. I've been using `sys.path.append()` so far, which was (and is) fine for me (I'm not a professional programmer) and I just want to know how to do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your application *only* from `main.py` (and no other relevant details regarding your problem are missing), then I would simply do like this:

Inside `MyFolder/main.py`, I would write:

```
from Folder2.foo2 import *  # Or import single functions or classes
```

and from inside `MyFolder/Folder2/foo2.py`, you write

```
from Folder1.foo1 import *
from Folder1.Subfolder1.subfoo1 import *
```

I reproduced your structure on my file system and I also tried it out, and it works for me.

If instead you also run as `__main__` the `MyFolder/Folder2/foo2.py` (as you said could possibly happen in a comment), then this won't work because in the following imports:

```
from Folder1.foo1 import *
from Folder1.Subfolder1.subfoo1 import *
```

Python would clearly not know what's `Folder1` (and all its subfolders or modules), since your new root folder is `Folder2`, and you can import modules or packages from the `__main__` file only if they are under the folder (or package) from where you run your `__main__` file.

You can solve this either by appending `MyFolder` to the `sys.path` (i.e. doing something similar to what you're already doing) or by setting up your project in a different way, that is by having under the root folder of your package a `setup.py` file. This last option, I would say, is actually the most serious option out there to deal with Python packages and modules, if you're not creating a toy program.

Check [this example](https://github.com/nbro/ands/blob/master/setup.py) of a `setup.py` that I created for one of my projects. But if you're interested in this option (and, if you have time, you should), I would encourage you to read a decent tutorial on how to create a project with a `setup.py` file and I would try to understand how and why it is useful, etc.

---

Regarding the `__init__.py` files. They are possibly empty files (but can contain runnable code and comments) which you put under folders of your project to indicate to Python to treat those folders as Python packages...I would again encourage you to read one (or more) tutorial(s) regarding the topic.

From Python 3.3 you don't need to put anymore these `__init__.py` files under your folders to make them be treated as packages.

So, if you're using a version previous to Python 3.3 and you do not include the `__init__.py` under the folders of your project, my first solution won't probably work (but I'm not sure 100%)...

Comment: Thx for the hint about the `setup.py`. I'll definitely study this a bit as soon as time permits.